# I have this python program and the output it came up just drive me crazy

Tags: python-3.x

```
print "This mode is called The Rat Population Change Mode(The Rat Maze Mode). The purpose of this mode is to determining the rat population change in each stage.By putting in the number of the steps you want to run this program, you can find out how the population has changed in each stage and a gragh wich indicates the change in visual."
n = input("Tell me the number of steps you want to run this progrem?:")


#Creat array and function for stage 1

Stage1 = zeros([n]) #Creat an array of value for stage 1

Stage1[0] = 50 #Creat the initial value of the stage 1 Array

Step1 = zeros([n]) #Creat Array of the population step in stage 1

def population1 (i):

    return Stage1[i - 1] + Stage4[i - 1] * 0.20 + Stage2[i - 1] * 0.20 - Stage1[i - 1] * 0.22

#Creat array and function for stage 2

Stage2 = zeros([n]) #Creat an array of value for stage 2

Stage2[0] = 40 #Creat the initial value of the stage 1 Array

Step2 = zeros([n]) #Creat Array of the population step in stage 2

def population2 (i):

    return Stage2[i - 1] + Stage3[i - 1] * 0.13

#Creat array and function for stage 3

Stage3 = zeros([n]) #Creat an array of value for stage 3

Stage3[0] = 50 #Creat the initial value of the stage 1 Array

Step3 = zeros([n]) #Creat Array of the population step in stage 3

def population3 (i):

    return Stage3[i - 1] - (Stage3[i - 1] * 0.20 + Stage3[i - 1] * 0.13 + Stage3[i - 1] * 0.16)

#Creat array and function for stage 4

Stage4 = zeros([n]) #Creat an array of value for stage 4

Stage4[0] = 10 #Creat the initial value of the stage 1 Array

Step4 = zeros([n]) #Creat Array of the population step in stage 4

def population4 (i):

    return Stage4[i - 1] + Stage1[i - 1] * 0.22 + Stage3[i - 1] * 0.16 - Stage4[i - 1] * 0.20 




#Creat the loop of population change and condition statement of each stage


i = 1

while i < n :

    Stage1[i] = population1 (i)
    if Stage1[i] < Stage1[i-1]  : #creat if statement for Stage 1
        PopulationChange1 = "decreased"
    elif Stage1[i] > Stage1[i-1] :
        PopulationChange1 = "increased"
    else :
        PopulationChange1 = "stayed the same"

    Stage2[i] = population2 (i)
    if Stage2[i] < Stage2[i-1]  : #creat if statement for Stage 2
        PopulationChange2 = "decreased"
    elif Stage2[i] > Stage2[i-1] :
        PopulationChange2 = "increased"
    else :
        PopulationChange2 = "stayed the same"

    Stage3[i] = population3 (i)
    if Stage3[i] < Stage3[i-1]  : #creat if statement for Stage 3
        PopulationChange3 = "decreased"
    elif Stage3[i] > Stage3[i-1] :
        PopulationChange3 = "increased"
    else :
        PopulationChange3 = "stayed the same"

    Stage4[i] = population4 (i)
    if Stage4[i] < Stage4[i-1]  : #creat if statement for Stage 4
        PopulationChange4 = "decreased"
    elif Stage4[i] > Stage4[i-1] :

        PopulationChange4 = "increased"
    else :
        PopulationChange4 = "stayed the same"

    Step1[i] = i #Creat statement for X axis in Stage 1
    Step2[i] = i #Creat statement for X axis in Stage 1
    Step3[i] = i #Creat statement for X axis in Stage 1
    Step4[i] = i #Creat statement for X axis in Stage 1

    i = i + 1


#print the value output and conditional statement for each stage

print " Stage 1 had an Initial Population of 50. After time step", n,", the population is", population1 (i)
print " The rat population after step",n,"in Stage 1 has",PopulationChange1,"from the initial rat population",Stage1[i-1]
print ""
print " Stage 2 had an Initial Population of 40. After time step", n,", the population is", population2 (i)
print " The rat population after step",n,"in Stage 2 has",PopulationChange2,"from the initial rat population",Stage2[i-1]
print ""
print " Stage 3 had an Initial Population of 50. After time step", n,", the population is", population3 (i)
print " The rat population after step",n,"in Stage 3 has",PopulationChange3,"from the initial rat population",Stage3[i-1]
print ""
print " Stage 4 had an Initial Population of 10. After time step", n,", the population is", population4 (i)
print " The rat population after step",n,"in Stage 4 has",PopulationChange4,"from the initial rat population",Stage4[i-1]
print ""

#plot the graph
plot(Step1, Stage1,linewidth=5, label='Stage 1')#plot(x,y,linewidth,label)
plot(Step2, Stage2,linewidth=5, label='Stage 2')
plot(Step3, Stage3,linewidth=5, label='Stage 3')
plot(Step4, Stage4,linewidth=5, label='Stage 4')

title ("The Rat Population Change Mode(The Rat Maze Mode)")
xlabel ("The Number of Steps")
ylabel ("The Change in The Population of Rat")

grid(True)
legend()

show()
```

the problem I have are :

1. if I put 1 in I got this output:Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:/Users/Kaiyiming/Desktop/Actual.py", line 110, in 
       print " The rat population after step",n,"in Stage 1 has",PopulationChange1,"from the initial rat population",Stage1[i-1]
   NameError: name 'PopulationChange1' is not defined
2. if I put 2 in I got this output:

   Stage 1 had an Initial Population of 50. After time step 2 , the population is 52.92
   The rat population after step 2 in Stage 1 has decreased from the initial rat population 49.0

It should be increased but it;s decreased in here.this only happened in stage 1 in step 1.I couldn't find out what the problem is.

Plz help me

Comment: question tagged as python3 but isnt.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that if `i < n`, you make `PopulationChange1` something. Therefore, when you put in the input as `1`, it only checks if `1 < 1` (`False`), and so never refers to `PopulationChange1`, raising a `NameError`.

To fix this, put `PopulationChange1 = PopulationChange2 = PopulationChange3 = PopulationChange4 = ""` at the beginning of your code.

Here is your edited code:

```
print "This mode is called The Rat Population Change Mode(The Rat Maze Mode). The purpose of this mode is to determining the rat population change in each stage.By putting in the number of the steps you want to run this program, you can find out how the population has changed in each stage and a gragh wich indicates the change in visual."
n = input("Tell me the number of steps you want to run this progrem?:")


#Add variables here to prevent error
PopulationChange1 = PopulationChange2 = PopulationChange3 = PopulationChange4 = ""
#Creat array and function for stage 1

Stage1 = zeros([n]) #Creat an array of value for stage 1

Stage1[0] = 50 #Creat the initial value of the stage 1 Array

Step1 = zeros([n]) #Creat Array of the population step in stage 1

def population1 (i):

    return Stage1[i - 1] + Stage4[i - 1] * 0.20 + Stage2[i - 1] * 0.20 - Stage1[i - 1] * 0.22

#Creat array and function for stage 2

Stage2 = zeros([n]) #Creat an array of value for stage 2

Stage2[0] = 40 #Creat the initial value of the stage 1 Array

Step2 = zeros([n]) #Creat Array of the population step in stage 2

def population2 (i):

    return Stage2[i - 1] + Stage3[i - 1] * 0.13

#Creat array and function for stage 3

Stage3 = zeros([n]) #Creat an array of value for stage 3

Stage3[0] = 50 #Creat the initial value of the stage 1 Array

Step3 = zeros([n]) #Creat Array of the population step in stage 3

def population3 (i):

    return Stage3[i - 1] - (Stage3[i - 1] * 0.20 + Stage3[i - 1] * 0.13 + Stage3[i - 1] * 0.16)

#Creat array and function for stage 4

Stage4 = zeros([n]) #Creat an array of value for stage 4

Stage4[0] = 10 #Creat the initial value of the stage 1 Array

Step4 = zeros([n]) #Creat Array of the population step in stage 4

def population4 (i):

    return Stage4[i - 1] + Stage1[i - 1] * 0.22 + Stage3[i - 1] * 0.16 - Stage4[i - 1] * 0.20 




#Creat the loop of population change and condition statement of each stage


i = 1

while i < n :

    Stage1[i] = population1 (i)
    if Stage1[i] < Stage1[i-1]  : #creat if statement for Stage 1
        PopulationChange1 = "decreased"
    elif Stage1[i] > Stage1[i-1] :
        PopulationChange1 = "increased"
    else :
        PopulationChange1 = "stayed the same"

    Stage2[i] = population2 (i)
    if Stage2[i] < Stage2[i-1]  : #creat if statement for Stage 2
        PopulationChange2 = "decreased"
    elif Stage2[i] > Stage2[i-1] :
        PopulationChange2 = "increased"
    else :
        PopulationChange2 = "stayed the same"

    Stage3[i] = population3 (i)
    if Stage3[i] < Stage3[i-1]  : #creat if statement for Stage 3
        PopulationChange3 = "decreased"
    elif Stage3[i] > Stage3[i-1] :
        PopulationChange3 = "increased"
    else :
        PopulationChange3 = "stayed the same"

    Stage4[i] = population4 (i)
    if Stage4[i] < Stage4[i-1]  : #creat if statement for Stage 4
        PopulationChange4 = "decreased"
    elif Stage4[i] > Stage4[i-1] :

        PopulationChange4 = "increased"
    else :
        PopulationChange4 = "stayed the same"

    Step1[i] = i #Creat statement for X axis in Stage 1
    Step2[i] = i #Creat statement for X axis in Stage 1
    Step3[i] = i #Creat statement for X axis in Stage 1
    Step4[i] = i #Creat statement for X axis in Stage 1

    i = i + 1


#print the value output and conditional statement for each stage

print " Stage 1 had an Initial Population of 50. After time step", n,", the population is", population1 (i)
print " The rat population after step",n,"in Stage 1 has",PopulationChange1,"from the initial rat population",Stage1[i-1]
print ""
print " Stage 2 had an Initial Population of 40. After time step", n,", the population is", population2 (i)
print " The rat population after step",n,"in Stage 2 has",PopulationChange2,"from the initial rat population",Stage2[i-1]
print ""
print " Stage 3 had an Initial Population of 50. After time step", n,", the population is", population3 (i)
print " The rat population after step",n,"in Stage 3 has",PopulationChange3,"from the initial rat population",Stage3[i-1]
print ""
print " Stage 4 had an Initial Population of 10. After time step", n,", the population is", population4 (i)
print " The rat population after step",n,"in Stage 4 has",PopulationChange4,"from the initial rat population",Stage4[i-1]
print ""

#plot the graph
plot(Step1, Stage1,linewidth=5, label='Stage 1')#plot(x,y,linewidth,label)
plot(Step2, Stage2,linewidth=5, label='Stage 2')
plot(Step3, Stage3,linewidth=5, label='Stage 3')
plot(Step4, Stage4,linewidth=5, label='Stage 4')

title ("The Rat Population Change Mode(The Rat Maze Mode)")
xlabel ("The Number of Steps")
ylabel ("The Change in The Population of Rat")

grid(True)
legend()

show()
```

Comment: thank you. What do you think about the second problem?

Comment: I don't get what is happening. The population goes from 50 to 52.92, but then you said it's decreasing?

Comment: the first output for stage 1 is 49,then the second is 52.92.it has increased. But in the output it said decreased. I dont know why it said decreased